# how to start the vncserver gui

Tags: vnc

I type vncserver and only a background thread starts. I enabled vnc through menu> preferences>raspberry pi configuration but no vnc server button appears at the top like I see in the [walkthrough](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/vnc-raspberry-pi/) but when I go back to configuration the vnc is greyed out but enabled so I can't disable it. How do I open the vnc server gui so I can login to the cloud account: [image]

Comment: Technically there is no gui for this sort of things. Either you can make one or use commands

Answer (score 2):

Enabling vnc from terminal: `sudo raspi-config > interfacing options > vnc > yes` resolved this.